# Excel change color of a column if x is in other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a problem with a spreadsheet that I have been working on for a bit at work. I need it to do the following:

I have an excel spreadsheet that has 5 columns. If column A through D has 1 or 2 "x" then column E is turned yellow. If column A through D has 3 or 4 "x" then column E is turned red.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use conditional formatting with a formula based on COUNTIF.

Comment: `COUNTIF(A:D,"x") < 3` for yellow and `AND(COUNTIF(A:D, "x") > 2, COUNTIF(A:D, "X") < 5)`. Or something of the sorts....

Comment: I figured it out. Just in case someone needs it: 
 =IF(OR(CONCATENATE(G2,H2,I2,J2)="X",CONCATENATE(G2,H2,I2,J2)="XX"),"Moderate",IF(OR(CONCATENATE(G2,H2,I2,J2)="XXX",CONCATENATE(G2,H2,I2,J2)="XXXX"),"High","Low"))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in the 2nd row.

1. Highlight all the cells you want this formatting for in Column E, starting with row 2 (or whichever is your first row of data
2. Go to `Conditional Formatting` in the `Home` part of your ribbon
3. Select `New Rule` then `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
4. Copy `=COUNTIFS($A2:$D2,"x")=2` and make the highlight the color you want (yellow)
5. Repeat steps 1-3 then copy `=COUNTIFS($A2:$D2,"x")>=3` and make the highlight the color you want (red)

You may have to adjust for a uppercase 'x' depending on the format of your data, but this should achieve what you're looking for. The key is to make sure the countif formula is referring to the row that you have activated so that way the formats line up properly.